# Show that $\{(1-t)^{\lambda}(1+t)^{2n-1-\lambda}, \lambda=0,1,...,2n-1\}$ forms a basis in $P_{2n-1}$, polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, independence

as stated above, I want to check wether $\{(1-t)^{\lambda}(1+t)^{2n-1-\lambda}, \lambda=0,1,...,2n-1\}$ forms a basis in $P_{2n-1}$, where $P_{2n-1}$ is the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal $2n-1$.

It has been used without any further comment in a paper of Walter Gautschi on Gaussian quadratur formulae,
https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/wxg/selected_works/section_07/128.pdf,
third page between (2.5) and (2.6).

I thought about showing the linear independence of these vectors, i.e. showing that $$\sum_{\lambda=0}^{2n-1} a_{\lambda}(1-t)^{\lambda}(1+t)^{2n-1-\lambda}=0 $$
implies that $a_{\lambda}=0$, $\lambda=0,1,\dots,2n-1$.

Didn't seem like a big problem, but induction for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ didn't work for me. Neither did I manage to get anything done with the binomial theorem.

I'd be grateful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The set $\{1,t,\dots,t^{2n-1}\}$ is a basis of $P_{2n-1}$, and the map $\Phi:P_{2n-1} \to P_{2n-1}$ defined by
$$
\Phi(f(t)) = (1-t)^{2n - 1} f\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t} \right) 
$$
is linear and invertible.

Comment: Ahh, I thought about transformation of the basis but didn't know how to do it precisely.
You mean $f(\frac{1+t}{1-t})$, right?
Anyway, thanks a lot for your good and very fast answer

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You're welcome!